# Running Same HTTP Request Multiple Times in Express Route

Tags: node.js, express

I am making a simple application with node and express which takes a CSV file of a schedule, converts it to JSON, and displays it in the browser.

However, I'm running into an issue with being able to download the CSV file multiple times in a single server instance.

The intended behavior is for the browser to hit a route and the server to run a function which retrieves a CSV file from a remote server. This runs fine after the server starts for the first time, but fails to retrieve the CSV a second time.

The route in question:

```
router.get('/', function(req,res,next) {
  getCsv.fromURL('exampleUrlHere/thing.csv', 'data/schedule.json');

  res.render('index');
});
```

And this is the helper I have it calling:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var request = require('request');
var Converter = require("csvtojson").Converter;
var csvToJson = new Converter({});


module.exports = {
    fromURL: function(csvFile, destination) {
        request.get(csvFile).pipe(csvToJson);
        csvToJson.on("end_parsed", function (jsonObj) {
           console.log(jsonObj); 
           fs.writeFile(destination, JSON.stringify(jsonObj),'utf8');

           console.log('JSON written from ' + csvFile + ' to ' + destination);
        });

    },
    asJSON: function() {
        var obj = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('data/schedule.json', 'utf8'));
        return obj;
    }
};
```

Might someone have some insight as to why the request fails after it is run for the first time?

Comment: don't know csvtojson but shouldn't you use a new one for each request?

Comment: your method fromUrl maybe asynchronous I think.